# SQL query speedup

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm trying to select N last unique keywords from table, which has the following structure:

```
id | keyword  | digit
1  | TEXT1    | 123
2  | TEXT2    | 125
...
3  | TEXT3    | 123
```

with query:

```
SELECT id, keyword FROM table 
WHERE digit = 123 
AND id IN 
(SELECT MAX(id) FROM table GROUP by keyword)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

when limit is 10 - 20, it takes less then a second, but if limit starts from 50 - query time begins from 3 sec and more.

Subselects is evil. Whether I can to speedup such query?

Comment: What indexes do you have on your table. What is the output of `explain`?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    SELECT MAX(id) max, keyword FROM table 
    WHERE digit = 123 
    GROUP BY keyword
    ORDER BY max DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: updated my answer , group by should do the work and when id is ordered DESC then you will get the max

Comment: Not really, it will sort by the first entry of `id` found... You would have to use the MAX()-function. [See SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb157/1/0)

Comment: This won't find unique keywords. If the same keyword appears more than once in the top 10, you'll get duplicates...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT MAX(id) as id, keyword FROM table
    WHERE digit = 123
    GROUP BY keyword 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Greetings.